# Pop range of elements in Stack

Tags: c#, stack

Hi guys i need a small help about Stack.Pop() function. 
As I know stack can pop out elements one by one, but I need more than one element to pop out. For example, I have 5 elements in stack (4,3,2,1,0) and now I want to pop out first 3 or 2 elements till stack index reaches 1 or 2.
by now I have "for" cycle which is not working correctly:

```
for(var i = stack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    stack.Pop();
}
```

Can someone please help me out, to let him pop out certain range of elements?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to pop until the stack only has a certain number of items left just use `while(stack.Count > desiredCount)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pop until the stack is a certain size just use

```
while(stack.Count > desiredCount)
    stack.Pop();
```

If you want to pop a certain number of items then just use

```
for(int i=0; i < numberOfItemsToPop && stack.Count > 0; i++)
    stack.Pop();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also create an Extension Method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> PopRange<T>(this Stack<T> stack, int amount)
    {
        var result = new List<T>(amount);
        while (amount-- > 0 && stack.Count > 0)
        {
            result.Add(stack.Pop());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And use it where you want:

```
var stack = new Stack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

var result = stack.PopRange(3);

// result: { 5, 4, 3 }
//  stack: { 2, 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using a simple while loop:

```
var stack = new Stack<int>(new[]{ 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 });

var numberToPop = 3;
while(numberToPop > 0 && stack.Count > 0)
{
    numberToPop--;
    stack.Pop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TryPopRange` of the `ConcurrentStack` class.

### Example:

```
var stack = new ConcurrentStack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
var resultPop = new int[2]; //Assume that we want to pop only 2 items.
int startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 1;

// The TryPopRange will pop 2 items from stack into resultPop.
if (stack.TryPopRange(resultPop, startIndex, endIndex) >= 1) //It returns the number of  popped item.
{
    Console.WriteLine($"This items has been popped: {string.Join(",", resultPop)}");
}
```